# How to add additional column based on the number of times it appear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (menu and orders) and I would like to label the items in the menu dataframe based on how popular it is (the number of times it appears in 'orders' dataframe).

```
import pandas as pd

menu = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Item_Name':['Chicken Pizza','Mushroom Soup','Tiramisu'],
    'Price':[8.99, 4.99, 5.99]})

orders = pd.DataFrame(
    {'order':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    'Item Name':['Chicken Pizza','Mushroom Soup','Tiramisu','Chicken Pizza','Chicken Pizza','Mushroom Soup','Chicken Pizza','Tiramisu']})
```

menu

```
        Item_Name    Price  
0   Chicken Pizza     8.99
1   Mushroom Soup     4.99
2        Tiramisu     5.99
```

orders

```
   order      Item Name  
0   1     Chicken Pizza    
1   2     Mushroom Soup
2   3          Tiramisu    
3   4     Chicken Pizza
4   5     Chicken Pizza    
5   6     Mushroom Soup    
6   7     Chicken Pizza    
7   8          Tiramisu
```

Desired Output:
"1" if item ordered is more than the median of all items ordered and "0" if it is less or equal to the median number of times ordered.

```
        Item_Name    Price    Popular
0   Chicken Pizza     8.99          1
1   Mushroom Soup     4.99          0
2        Tiramisu     5.99          0
```

I tried using this syntax but it does not work.

```
menu["Popular"] = lambda x: 1 if orders["Item Name"].count() > orders["Item Name"].median() else 0
```

Comment: [`median`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is the middle value in a sorted list. What would be the median in your case with a list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to [`groupby count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) to get the number of each item. Then we can compare this to the [`median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.median.html) of the *counts* not the entire DataFrame, convert the True/False values to 1/0 ([`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)), and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to `menu` on the `Item_Name` column:

```
counts = orders.groupby('Item Name')['Item Name'].count()
menu = menu.join(
    (counts > counts.median()).astype(int).rename('Popular'),
    on='Item_Name'
)
```

Or with [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) instead of `groupby count`:

```
counts = orders['Item Name'].value_counts()
menu = menu.join(
    (counts > counts.median()).astype(int).rename('Popular'),
    on='Item_Name'
)
```

Either way gets `menu`:

```
       Item_Name  Price  Popular
0  Chicken Pizza   8.99        1
1  Mushroom Soup   4.99        0
2       Tiramisu   5.99        0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `groupby` "Item Name" + `size` to count the items, then compute the median and find elements greater than (`gt`) it. The output being a boolean, one converts to int by changing type. Finally `merge` the output Series of 0/1s with the "menu":

```
s = orders.groupby('Item Name').size()
menu.merge(s.gt(s.median()).astype(int).rename('Popular'),
           left_on='Item_Name', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
       Item_Name  Price  Popular
0  Chicken Pizza   8.99        1
1  Mushroom Soup   4.99        0
2       Tiramisu   5.99        0
```